# Is it possible for a module to have event listeners that will react to application events?

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

I am very new to Quarkus and I would like to know if it is possible to have a separate module registering (and reacting) to application (custom) event listeners.

I am trying Quarkus by writing a simple JavaSE application. My building tool is Gradle.

I was able to register the listener on a separte package in the main module (where the QuarkusMain application resides), but as soon as I move the listener to a separate module, it won't even be instantiated.

I could not find many examples online for multi-module builds with Quarkus and Gradle. I tried the following, after reading the guide and forums online with no success:

- I first moved the working listener (annotated with @ApplicationScope) to a new module and applied the kordamp Jandex plugin,
- I then added an empty `bean.xml` file under the `META-INF` folder under `resouces`,
- I even marked the bean with `@Startup`, but it was never instantiated
- I then created a non-annotated Configuration class with the method that instantiates the bean marked with `@Produces` and `@ApplicationScope`, but it was never instantiated. I even tried adding `@Startup` with no luck
- Following an online suggestion (and even though this is not what I want to achieve), I injecting the listener in a field in the main application, but Quarkus cannot find the bean. I even tried injecting the it with `@Inject Instance<MyListener> listener` following another suggestion, but I had no luck.

I wish there was a simple working example in the guides for this simple setup with Gradle but, in the meantime, could anyone please tell me how I can achieve this? Once I have the initial guide, I will give it a try and post a code example if necessary.

If I get it to work, I will share how I made it work.

Thank you!